# Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, html-table, pdf-generation

I have an desing page(.cshtml) document that renders fine in all browser(FireFox, Chrome and IE). It uses fairly basic CSS to style it and renders fine in HTML.

I'm trying to convert it's one DIV to PDF, but I am facing issue like white spaces and page break. I have tried:

jsPDF : It had huge problems with HTML tables. I factored out my large tables and it helped but it makes a complete mess of tables and doesn't seem to get images. The tables were just break after page end. It doesn't print properly.

Windows Print : I also simply tried with windows print option in javascript, but it automatically takes the site logo image on every page of PDF and it get overlaped on data lines.

nReco : I also tried with nReco tool to convert HTML to PDF, but I am getting same output as above.

What am I missing, or how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using html2pdf library as it is an easier to implement library. I have myself faced issues with jspdf and html2pdf has helped solve complex svg/grid related issues.